# How to rebuild the JDK JNI C code for ServerSocketChannelImpl in Java?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, real-time, nio

I downloaded the JDK sources and I am trying to make a modification in the `ServerSocketChannelImpl`. The [ServerSocketChannelImpl.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/raw-file/ffa98eed5766/src/share/classes/sun/nio/ch/ServerSocketChannelImpl.java) uses native code for the `accept0` method. The native code for this method is in [ServerSocketChannelImpl.c](http://svn.netlabs.org/repos/java/trunk/openjdk/jdk/src/solaris/native/sun/nio/ch/ServerSocketChannelImpl.c). I need to make a small change there and rebuild the `.so` library so I can use it with my JVM.

When I build my own general JNI library, i use a `gcc` command-line as below:

```
gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/include/linux/ -fPIC -o libHello.so -shared org_tsutils_Hello.c
```

But for the JVM C source code I am not sure how to proceed. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: jdk7 instructions may give some pointers - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/build/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html

Answer (score -1):

if you are implement native method you should run javah on your code and it will generate h files that will fill the c++ code that you have now you add the compilation product including the header to your class path.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Read it. He is asking how to recompile and rebuke an existing JNI library, not how to start from scratch with a new one.

Comment: why not rebuild the project from scratch, what is the diffrence?